# Serving static files with Spring 4 (Annotations)

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have simple Spring 4 application:

```
package proj;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

I'd like to serve static content from **/resources** folder, also I have file **resources/1.txt** which I made for testing.

I created class **Application** in the root folder, also I created another folder **config/** in the root folder, in the **config/** I created a new class **WebMvcConfig** and added the code:

```
package proj.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
}
```

Then I tried to get file **1.txt** from my **/resources** folder by query:

> http://localhost:8080/resources/1.txt

But I get **404 error not found**. I can't understand why it doesn't work.

I will really appreciate if somebody can help me to solve that problem.

Comment: What did you mean by "root folder"? Would it work if you put `1.txt` into the `src/main/resources/resources`?

Comment: I don't think you need the WebMvcConfig file at all. In a Spring Boot app, the resources folder is a static content folder by default.

Comment: I have created resources/resources but it doesn't work. Root folder = default package folder.

Comment: " the resources folder is a static content folder by default." - If so which URL will give me 1.txt file?

Comment: @szmeti yes, you are right, but I can get file by http://localhost:8080/1.txt URL, but I can't get it by http://localhost:8080/resources/1.txt . How to change the behavior?

Comment: Probably, you need `.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/")`

Comment: So, this helped me : registry.addResourceHandler("/res/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/"); I don't know why classpath is so essential here, it only work with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem.

```
package proj.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/");    
    }
}
```

So, I don't know why **"classpath:" prefix** is essential to make that work.

By default (as was said in comments above) Spring serve static from root URL.

For example `localhost:8080/1.txt` , but if you want change Spring behavior and you have the same problem as I had, so just try code above.

Also, may be that link will be useful: https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot